# Java adding constants to dynamicly added code

Tags: java, focuslistener

is it possible to add a constant to code added to an object?  So if my psudo code below where run then the object in question gained focus what ever value was in ZZZ at the time would be printed out?

```
public void addStupidListener(JTextField textField, String ZZZ) {
    textField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("selected" + ZZZ);
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("de-selected" + ZZZ);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What happens when you compile and run this code?

Comment: So to make this more general, you are asking if you can use a stack variable in an Anonymous class?

Comment: i feel really stupid my code works as writen

Comment: I think you will get a compiler error if you don't make the "ZZZ" `String` final

Comment: figure it out: eclipse allows it if the variable is final or effectively final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can capture stack variables in Anonymous classes. Here's an example. I assume what you are trying to do will work.

```
public class AnonymousTest {


    public static void main(String[] args){

        Object obj = someObject("Hey world!");
        System.out.println(obj);
    }

    public static Object someObject(String str){
        return new Object(){
            public String toString(){
                return super.toString()+str;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Output: stackoverflow.AnonymousTest$1@7f31245aHey world!

Answer (score 0):

No this won't be work. You mixed initialization and execution code. You put a listener for future execution, how it can takes the String when you initializes it. Don't do stuff like this, its very irritating.

Comment: i did not think it would work as writen.  I was hoping there was a way to code it.  However it does actually work.